# Page does not render after SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdownlist in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, aspwizard

I have one dropdownlist (with static listitems). On SelectedIndexChanged event of this dropdownlist, I have three cases to check:

1) If the value is 'A', I need to bind another dropdownlist.
2) If value is 'B', I need to hide above another dropdownlist and instead show nothing in place of that i.e. ulitmately hide that particular div.
3) If values is 'C', I need to hide above div and in place of that, show a textbox.

Now, to prevent Page postback each time a value in dropdownlist is changed, I am using UpdatePanel control here.

I have tried using single updatepanel for both these dropdownlists, two separate udpatePanels for each of them.

With two separate updatePanels, I could succeed in calling the "SelectedIndexChanged" event of that dropdownlist, but once the event is called, the changes done in that code are not reflecting on the page.

i.e. if I hide a div when selected value is 'B', it still shows me, or in either case if it is 'A' and I bind another dropdown, it does not even render.

And, if I reload that page, the pervious changes get reflected. Can anybody please tell me what could be wrong here?

Also, please note that I want be able to postback the page programmatically, because that is the I am trying to prevent.

Also, I would like to notify here that I am using all these things in a WizrdStep of an asp.net wizard control.

Would be greatful for any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What was the problem with a single `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: show some code, what are you really doing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not because of update panel or dropdownlist.

The problem was with the way my page was being rendered.

I have used url rewriting for my application and I was trying render this page using my customized form tag instead of built-in Html form tag.

That is why updatepanel was not working normally.

I have got it working now using normal Html Form tag and meanwhile I am trying to workout to handle this updatepanel tag as well with my customized form tag.

If I get it solved, I will submit the solution.

Thanks.